# rails tailwindcss:build ELF not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My ruby version is 3.1.2 and rails version is 7.0.6 .When I successfully executed “bundle add tailwindcss rails”。The installed version is tailwindcss rails 2.0.30 (x86_64 Linux)。
I failed to execute “rails tailwindcss: install” and generated garbled files。

Websites：
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails
Here's my error report:

```
zgl@LAPTOP-9FJ4SQII:/mnt/d/zgl/my_block$ rails tailwindcss:install
Add Tailwindcss include tags and container element in application layout
insert app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Build into app/assets/builds
exist app/assets/builds
create app/assets/builds/.keep
append app/assets/config/manifest.js
append .gitignore
Add default config/tailwindcss.config.js
create config/tailwind.config.js
Add default app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css
create app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css
Add default Procfile.dev
create Procfile.dev
Ensure foreman is installed
run gem install foreman from "."
Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2
Parsing documentation for foreman-0.87.2
Done installing documentation for foreman after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
Add bin/dev to start foreman
create bin/dev
Compile initial Tailwind build
run rails tailwindcss:build from "."
/home/zgl/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.30-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss: 1: �ELF����: not found
/home/zgl/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.30-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
rails aborted!
Command failed with exit 2: /home/zgl/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.30-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss

Tasks: TOP => tailwindcss:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F6kt.png)
I have tried Google related issues but have not been resolved. I hope to receive help

Comment: And you're sure you're on x86_64 hardware?